# How to extract JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have been trying to get the Object from the below json using JS. 
Its a direct variables but still there is no success .
i have tired using For loops no luck
i have tried using JSON.parse this gives me error. 
        **console.log('-0-' + JSON.stringify(getTotalProducts));**

and even hardcoding the JSON Array is not working

So when you this JSON Object i have list of records like this `a4wg0000000sdsGAA0`, `a4wg000000asdaMGAA0` and so on. 
I want to get the direct variable called totalCogs. How do i get that?

```
{
  "a4wg0000000uioGAA0": {
    "familyMap": {
      "MS Hardware": {
        "familyName": "MS Hardware",
        "familySObj": {
          "Name": "MS Hardware",
          "Sort_Order__c": 2,
          "Task_Code__c": "4",
          "Targeted_GM__c": 0.3,
          "Family_Trigger_Date__c": "Manuf_Equipment_Elect_Buyouts_Trigger__c",
          "Id": "a4ug000000052IjAAI"
        },
        "productsInFamily": [],
        "sortOrder": 2,
        "groupsInFamily": [],
        "groupsInFamilyByGroupName": {},
        "isBooking": false,
        "isFee": false,
        "totalUnits": 0,
        "totalCogs": 0,
        "totalStdCost": 0,
        "totalRevenue": 0,
        "totalTargetedSellPrice": 0,
        "targetedSell": 0,
        "targetedMargin": 0,
        "spreadGrossMarginSell": 0,
        "percentTotal": 0,
        "totalCalcdMargin": 0
      }
    },
    "rateMap": {
      "GBP": 1,
      "AUD": "1.87999999",
      "BRL": "5.39999999",
      "CAD": "1.75999999",
      "CLP": "986.66765087",
      "CNY": "9.93333315",
      "DKK": "8.73040009",
      "EUR": "1.12000000",
      "JPY": "149.79994180",
      "MXN": "26.26666728",
      "MYR": "5.43999997",
      "SEK": "0.14666667",
      "SGD": "1.80000000",
      "THB": "42.26666834"
    },
    "marginTotalStdCost": 94751,
    "marginTotalCogs": 94751,
    "marginTotalTargetedSellPrice": 103347,
    "marginTotalTargetedCalcdMargin": 0.08317609606471399,
    "bookingTotalStdCost": 101740,
    "bookingTotalCogs": 101740,
    "bookingTotalTargetedSellPrice": 110336,
    "bookingTotalTargetedCalcdMargin": 0.07790748259860791,
    "totalStdCost": 101740,
    "totalCogs": 101740,
    "totalTargetedSellPrice": 110336,
    "totalTargetedCalcdMargin": 0.07790748259860791,
    "marginTotalRevenue": 135361,
    "marginTotalCalcdMargin": 0.3000125590088726,
    "bookingTotalRevenue": 142350,
    "bookingTotalCalcdMargin": 0.2852827537759045,
    "totalRevenue": 142350,
    "totalCalcdMargin": 0.2852827537759045,
    "systemISO": "USD"
  }
}
```

Comment: @briosheje — There's no `const foo =` at the front. It *could* be a JSON text.

Comment: "i have tired using For loops" — How? "i have tried using JSON.parse this gives me error" — How? What error? "even hardcoding the JSON Array" — How? What array? There's a couple of arrays in that data, all empty.

Comment: @briosheje — mmm, I hadn't noticed that typo. It wouldn't be valid JavaScript either though.

Comment: @Quentin me neither, what I first did was copy -> paste on jsonlint, saw error and was like "Ok, it's an object, then", but it's not a valid object either.

Comment: Its has 28K lines
I have edited the JSON again.

Comment: For loop i tired is 
`for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(getTotalProducts).length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(getTotalProducts)[i].length; j++) {
console.log('-2-' + Object.keys(getTotalProducts)[i][j]["totalCogs"]);
}
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to access the value of totalCogs even when you don't know the key name

I think this will help you

```js
var jsonData=`{
   "a4wg0000000uioGAA0":{
      "familyMap":{
         "MS Hardware":{
            "familyName":"MS Hardware",
            "familySObj":{
               "Name":"MS Hardware",
               "Sort_Order__c":2,
               "Task_Code__c":"4",
               "Targeted_GM__c":0.3,
               "Family_Trigger_Date__c":"Manuf_Equipment_Elect_Buyouts_Trigger__c",
               "Id":"a4ug000000052IjAAI"
            },
            "productsInFamily":[

            ],
            "sortOrder":2,
            "groupsInFamily":[

            ],
            "groupsInFamilyByGroupName":{

            },
            "isBooking":false,
            "isFee":false,
            "totalUnits":0,
            "totalCogs":0,
            "totalStdCost":0,
            "totalRevenue":0,
            "totalTargetedSellPrice":0,
            "targetedSell":0,
            "targetedMargin":0,
            "spreadGrossMarginSell":0,
            "percentTotal":0,
            "totalCalcdMargin":0
         }
      },
      "rateMap":{
         "GBP":1,
         "AUD":"1.87999999",
         "BRL":"5.39999999",
         "CAD":"1.75999999",
         "CLP":"986.66765087",
         "CNY":"9.93333315",
         "DKK":"8.73040009",
         "EUR":"1.12000000",
         "JPY":"149.79994180",
         "MXN":"26.26666728",
         "MYR":"5.43999997",
         "SEK":"0.14666667",
         "SGD":"1.80000000",
         "THB":"42.26666834"
      },
      "marginTotalStdCost":94751,
      "marginTotalCogs":94751,
      "marginTotalTargetedSellPrice":103347,
      "marginTotalTargetedCalcdMargin":0.08317609606471399,
      "bookingTotalStdCost":101740,
      "bookingTotalCogs":101740,
      "bookingTotalTargetedSellPrice":110336,
      "bookingTotalTargetedCalcdMargin":0.07790748259860791,
      "totalStdCost":101740,
      "totalCogs":101740,
      "totalTargetedSellPrice":110336,
      "totalTargetedCalcdMargin":0.07790748259860791,
      "marginTotalRevenue":135361,
      "marginTotalCalcdMargin":0.3000125590088726,
      "bookingTotalRevenue":142350,
      "bookingTotalCalcdMargin":0.2852827537759045,
      "totalRevenue":142350,
      "totalCalcdMargin":0.2852827537759045,
      "systemISO":"USD"
   }
}`;
var jsonParsedData=JSON.parse(jsonData);

for (var data in jsonParsedData) {
  console.log("totalCogs")
  console.log('-2-'+jsonParsedData[data].totalCogs)
}
```

also a multple object example on [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/bezemef/edit?js,console)

Comment: You are the best man !! others wanted to just downvote, whereas you have created a list and showed how to traverse through the object.

Comment: if i want to get that a4wg0000000uioGAA0, how to get that value?

Comment: `var jsonParsedData=JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(jsonParsedData.a4wg0000000uioGAA0.totalCogs)`

Answer (score 0):

The json you first posted was invalid and couldn't be parsed.

With valid json you can get totalCogs like this:

```
var jsonData='{ json data here... }';

var result = JSON.parse(jsonData);

console.log(result.a4wg0000000uioGAA0.totalCogs);
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3wdkovy/)